# How to open a window in asp:updatepanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, popup

I have a pop-up `CustomControl` which I use in a large-scale web application. The pop-up works well everywhere other than when used inside an `asp:UpdatePanel`, the problem arises when controlling the visibility of the pop-up (the pop-up is nested in a table) with other controls:

When I click the button to open the window I get **`Error: Object expected`** and when I try to debug the error with `IE 8` JSEditor I get **``Source Code is not available for this location**.

I believe that the code of the pop-up is not being initialized completely, but it is just my guess and I don't know how to resolve this issue.

Any help or ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any code we can refer to?

Comment: @ Mr. Disappointment, here is the UI code http://codepaste.net/p8oq2t

Comment: Cool, but I've read shorter books before. Do you have any _relevant_ code we can refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't get to see that question title has a lot to do with the subject at hand,

Most (if not all) `Object Expected` error occurs when you add a reference on your page to a JavaScript file which doesn't exist or cannot be opened.

When you run your website in debug-mode, VS will put another pseudo-project in solution explorer, navigate through the files there and you will find the already loaded-version of JS, you can set breakpoints there and see what code exactly is "not available".

**Note:** This is for Web Applications, I'm not sure if it applies to Project-less Websites.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunatelyI'musing a WebSite, by the way When I navigate to Page source (in IE) it can't browse a peace of code. and I'm not sure that asp:updatepanel let the control completely initialize or not

Answer (score 0):

Does this work in other browsers? Have you tried Firefox and Firebug to investigate the issue or is this specific to IE.

Having code in an ASP:UpdatePanel means that the Microsoft Ajax javascript include will be loaded and come an interfere with the object model you are normally expecting to get. Are you certain of the id or name you are trying to find as this might not be returning an Object hence the error.

I have used jQuery and classes and styles to add behaviour after the page loads to avoid id issues. The [`$jQuery.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function is useful to ensure handlers get bound to items delivered to the page with MS Ajax.